# How to convert Microsoft Network Monitor `.cap` file to `.pcap` or `pcapng`?

Tags: type-conversion, wireshark, pcap, cap, editcap

When I tried to use editcap to convert `.cap` to `.pcap`, I got:

> 'editcap: The capture file being read can't be written as a ".pcap" file.'

The `.cap` file generated by Microsoft Network Monitor looks very special, which contains application and other information. How to convert it to something similar to the ".pcap" generated by Wireshark.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't forget to accept an answer (check-mark next to the answer) if it answers your question (consider also up-voting the answer). In this way your question stops from popping up as unanswered in question searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use Wireshark itself to convert the file as you seem to have run into Wireshark [Bug 15482](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15482) - **editcap can't convert a NetMon 2.x capture file to pcapng, even though Wireshark can do it.**

Unfortunately, there has been no traction with resolving that bug in over a year, so it doesn't appear to be a high priority bug or on anyone's radar.  You can try voting for the bug or even better - submitting a patch to fix it if you're able to.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have two more questions:
1. My NetMon version is 3.4.
2. It cannot be saved as other format even in WireShark, because the the `save as` button is grey.

Comment: I don't think the Netmon version is the same as the Netmon file format.  You can check the file format in Wireshark under *"Statistics -> Capture File Properties -> Format"* or on the command-line with `capinfos -t file.cap`.

Comment: Interestingly, I can no longer convert the file using Wireshark version 3.2.4 or with master v3.3.0rc0-1640-g7184c1bce2d8.  When I filed the bug, I was using an older version, v3.1.0rc0-8-g53b55bfb.  I also tried with version 2.6.6 but that version of Wireshark doesn't allow it to be saved in another format either.  It would seem something changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, you are right, the Netmon file format is NetMon 2.x. Anyway, I switched to Pyshark to open the.cap file, so there is no need to convert .cap to .pcap which is Scapy can read type.